# Find number of array elements

Tags: matlab

Let A(1:8, -5:5, -10:5) be a three dimensional array. How many elements are there in the array A?

Can anyone tell how to find the number of elements **manually**. I don't have much knowledge in matlab

Comment: Edited in the manual requirement based on the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you seem to be interested in checking it manually, perhaps to review matlab code, here is the trick:

- `1:8` has `8-1+1 = 8` elements
- `-5:5` has `5--5+1 = 11` elements
- `-10:5` has `5--10+1 = 16` elements

So the result is:

The matrix has `8*11*16 = 1408` elements in total.

Answer (score 4):

Use [***`numel`***](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/numel.html)
function to get number of array elements.

`n_of_elements = numel( A ) ;`

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is:

```
n_of_elements = prod(size(A))
```

Comment: if size(Matrix) = [3,4,5], then number of total elements in that matrix is equal to 3x4x5 = 60 elements.